# Cannot read property 'parentNode'

Tags: javascript

I'm beginning to learn javascript, and I can't figure out for the life of me, why this 'Cannot read property 'parentNode'' is getting thrown in the console; and why the for loop is calling an after the third link.

I was following a lesson on javascript rollovers, the rollover works, but why is the error being thrown?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  #caption, #content {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10%;
    line-height: 1.675em;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  window.onload = initRollover;

  function initRollover() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {  
      console.log(i);  
      if(document.images[i].parentNode.tagName == "A") {
        setupRollover(document.images[i]);
      } 
      document.links[i].setAttribute('class', 'test');
    }
  }

  function setupRollover(thisImage){
    thisImage.outImage = new Image();
    thisImage.outImage.src = thisImage.src;
    thisImage.onmouseout = function() {
      this.src = this.outImage.src;
    }

    thisImage.overImage = new Image();
    thisImage.overImage.src = "images/" + "silver" + ".jpg";
    thisImage.onmouseover = function(){
      this.src = this.overImage.src;
    }
  }
</script>

<div id="content" style="background: lightgreen;">
  <img src="images/silver.jpg" width="240" alt="Silver" id="photoA">
  <br><br>
  <a href="boom.html">
    <img src="images/gold.jpg" width="240" alt="Gold" id="photoB">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="caption">
  <a href="foo.html">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</a> consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. <a href="bar.html">Duis aute irure dolor </a>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in <a href="car.html">culpa qui officia deserunt</a> mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're looping over `document.links` but then using `document.images[i]` within the loop. So if you have more links than you do images you'll get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure as to what you are trying to achieve. But the problem i see is here

```
function initRollover() {
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {  
  console.log(i);  
  if(document.images[i].parentNode.tagName == "A") {
    setupRollover(document.images[i]);
  } 
  document.links[i].setAttribute('class', 'test');
}
}
```

In you html code, there are 3 links with  tags but only 2 images with  tag. So when i = 2, there is no document.images[2]. Hence the parentNode is null. That leads to your error.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I was trying to run a For loop to find out how many links there were overall (4), and then target any links that had images as children, or if there are any images with a parent link, target that. I'm just seeing why that If statement is causing errors, cause if there are no images with link parent, then doesn't it get skipped?

Comment: Oh okay. I get the purpose now. So the problem is when you are using document.links and document.images, you are counting them all. There are 2 ways to approach this
1. You can use your way. But you have to enclose that whole statement in a try ... catch block. Handle the error in case the parent link doesn't exist.
2. The easier way would be to look at the innerHtml of each link and search for images in that.

Cheers!!

Comment: Ahh okay. That makes more sense probably. Thanks.